# How to get vimeo id from "friendly" url

Tags: php, ajax, vimeo

As we know, vimeo videos usually have the following appearance:

```
http://vimeo.com/123456
```

But yesterday I saw, that some videos are different, like this one:

```
https://vimeo.com/donialiechti/stranded
```

It's interesting, that when you click the link, you'll see in the address bar

```
http://vimeo.com/64334084
```

Embed code for this video is:

```
<iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/64334084"... ></iframe>
```

The problem is that my app needs to know video id to work properly.
**So how a "friendly" url can be converted into a regular vimeo id?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far that failed?

Comment: I haven't any idea how to do it.

Comment: Well then, what did you search for? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=following+url+php&aq=f&oq=following+url+php&aqs=chrome.0.57j62l3.3009j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Vimeo sends the redirect information in HTTP headers, you can fetch them like this:

```
function fetch_vimeo_id($url) {
    $headers = get_headers($url);
    # Reverse loop because we want the last matching header,
    # as Vimeo does multiple redirects with your `https` URL
    for($i = count($headers) - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
        $header = $headers[$i];
        if(strpos($header, "Location: /") === 0) {
            return substr($header, strlen("Location: /"));
        }
    }
    # Could not find id
    return null;
}

echo fetch_vimeo_id("https://vimeo.com/donialiechti/stranded");
```

Output:

```
64334084
```

Answer (score 3):

A better way to solve this problem would be to use [Vimeo's OEmbed API](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/oembed).

The video_id is included in the response, and it accepts all of Vimeo's possible video endpoints.

Comment: While I like that as a solution, us web developers working in Javascript unfortunately cannot take full advantage given the lack of JSONP

Comment: I believe  the oembed endpoint properly supports CORS headers. You should be able to make these requests just fine without JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

check below solution, it works.

i.e. :

```
http://vimeo.com/11111111
http://player.vimeo.com/video/11111111
http://vimeo.com/channels/channelname/11111111
http://vimeo.com/groups/groupname/11111111
```

Code :

```
    $vimeoUrl = 'http://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/11111111';
    $fetchVimeoIdArr = explode('/', $vimeoUrl);
    $idCounter = count($fetchVimeoIdArr) - 1;
    $vimeoId = $fetchVimeoIdArr[$idCounter];
```